# Decompose the following relation into BCNF

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

Given a Relation R with attributes A, B, C, D, E and set of Functional Dependencies A->B, BC->E, ED->A. Decompose it into high normal form.

Comment: Please show what you are able to do. Google 'stackexchange homework' &  read [ask]. We're not here to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of **[candidate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key)**:

> In the relational model of databases, a candidate key of a relation is
>   a minimal superkey for that relation; that is, a set of attributes
>   such that:
>
> 1. The relation does not have two distinct tuples (i.e. rows or records in common database language) with the same values for these
>      attributes (which means that the set of attributes is a superkey)
> 2. There is no proper subset of these attributes for which (1) holds (which means that the set is minimal).

Given the F.D's only `C` and `D` come on the left side, which means every key must possess `C` and `D`.

closure(CD) is not equal to all attributes, however, from the F.D's we can clearly see that:

closure(CDA) = closure(CDB) = closure(CDE) = set of all attributes, this means that all three `CDA`, `CDB` and `CDE` are candidate keys.

Now let us follow the BCNF decomposition algorithm given in this [stanford lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfVCesoMaGA&index=21&list=PLFt4E5CtqucwbD_JY0ljS0VWu7Pfwoeu1).

> Given a schema R.
>
> 1. Compute keys for R.
> 2. Repeat until all relations are in BCNF.
>
>    - Pick any R' having a F.D A --> B that violates BCNF.
>    - Decompose R' into R1(A,B) and R2(A,Rest of attributes).
>    - Compute F.D's for R1 and R2.
>    - Compute keys for R1 and R2.

`A-->B` violates BCNF as A is not a key, so we decompose R into

R1(A,C,D,E) and R2(A,B).

R2 is in BCNF now, but R1 is not due to F.D `ED-->A`, as `ED` is not a key. So we decompose R1 further as:

R3(C,D,E) and R4(A,E,D), now clearly both R3 an R4 are in BCNF.

Comment: From what source are these quotations being taken? You need to include a *link* to that source, along with the name of the author, in your answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing